# Find position of max value in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 2*3 matrix ranging from cells C2:E3. I need to find the row number of the maximum number

Can someone suggest a VBA code for the same
I tried to use index and match but not getting proper results

Comment: what have you tried so far? SO is not a free coding service :)

Comment: I tried to use address (match(C:C),C:C,0),1,4). But this can only return the row number of max value in column C alone and similarly for other columns....but I needed the position of overall row that had maximum value.

Comment: Shai Rado has guided me. And it did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindMaxValRow()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim MaxCell As Range
Dim MaxVal As Long

Set Rng = Range("C2:E3")
MaxVal = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)

' use the Find function to get the Row number
Set MaxCell = Rng.Find(what:=MaxVal, LookIn:=xlValues)

MsgBox "Maximum value found at row " & MaxCell.Row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA-free solution:

Assuming that the table is in `$C$2:$E$3`, 
an **array formula** (type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=MAX((MAX($C$2:$E$3)=$C$2:$E$3)*ROW($C$2:$E$3))
```

returns the maximal row number, in which the maximal element is found.

[image]

To get the minimal row number, in which the maximal element is found,
we can use this **array formula**:

```
=ROW($C$3:$E$3)-MAX((MAX($C$2:$E$3)=$C$2:$E$3)*(ROW($C$3:$E$3)-ROW($C$2:$E$3)))
```

[image]