# Row number of Maximum value in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find the maximum value in a range and get the row number of     the row where that maximum value occurs

```
Sub MaximumValue()

Dim MaxVal As Double
Dim Row As Long

Set Workrange = Selection
MaxVal = Application.Max(Workrange)
Range(MaxVal).Select
Row = ActiveCell.Row

MsgBox "MaxValue is in Row" & Row

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find position of max value in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542490/find-position-of-max-value-in-excel)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `Find` function to find `MaxVal` in `Workrange`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MaximumValue()

Dim MaxVal As Double
Dim Workrange As Range, FndRng As Range
Dim lRow As Long

Set Workrange = Selection
MaxVal = Application.Max(Workrange)

Set FndRng = Workrange.Find(what:=MaxVal)
lRow = FndRng.Row

MsgBox "MaxValue is in Row " & lRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mate! Worked, was using a loop. This is much more elegant.